# Cannot locate Ubuntu Software Center via Firefox to open APT links

Tags: apt, software-center, firefox

I'm trying to locate where the Ubuntu Software Center is to choose as default for handling APT links in Firefox.  I can click on the links, and I get the pop-up, but Ubuntu Software Center is not there.  I tried to choose an application through Firefox's settings and through the pop-up, but I don't know the path.  As you can see by my screen shot for the pop-up I chose the wrong one as that doesn't work.  What is the correct path I need to select the correct file?

EDIT - I added a fourth screen shot.  I don't have it in that location.  This is what I have.  My view is in ABC order, and it's showing hidden files.

[image: USC1]

[image: USC2]

[image: USC3]

[image: USC4]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You need to locate the `/usr/share/software-center/software-center` file.

I ran the `which` command, and it showed it was in `/usr/bin/software-center` but even showing hidden files it's not there. So I check the link that was there labeled "software-center", and it showed it went to `/usr/share/software-center/software-center` and it was a Python script.  Well I tried to choose that when clicking on a link, and it opened as it should, so I guess that's it, or at least it works.  It even shows in Firefox's settings under the Application tab.

[image: screenshoot]

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for "/usr/bin/software-center"

Comment: I don't have it in that location.  I edited my OP with that location to show where you are saying.  I even did a full search for the executable, but can't find it anywhere.  It has to be somewhere, otherwise I couldn't open the USC at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use aptURL to handle apt links. It comes pre-installed in your ubuntu machine, and I think it's what the ubuntu software center actually uses, so you skip a step.

You will find it in /usr/bin/apturl

You can read more about aptURL [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptURL).

Answer (score 0):

if you are not able to find the path just follow the directions written below:

1.first open the **file** logo from the left panel of desktop.

2.then go to **computer** selected from the device category.

3.select **usr** in the right side.

4.select **share** in the **usr** folder

5.select **software center" in the **share" folder.

6.select **software-center** file in **software center** folder.

7.and you are done.

hope i'll help you.